# Property of type class not entering the setter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

I have a user control with a property called SightGlass:

```
public SightGlassData SightGlass
{
    get
    {
        return _sightGlass;
    }
    set
    {
        //This code is never entered!
        _sightGlass = value;
        CalculateSightGlassRect();
    }
}
```

The `SightGlassData` class is defined as follows with a type converter to enabling editing of the single properties from the properties window in Visual Studio at design-time:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SightGlassData
{
    //Various public properties in here...
}
```

**Issue:**
I add the user control to a form in Visual Studio at design-time. When editing a sub-property in the property `SightGlass` of the user control from the properties window of Visual Studio at design-time, the property is changed as expected, but the setter of the property in the user control is not entered.

This means that the function `CalculateSightGlassRect()` is never called, thus I can't update my user control visually at design-time.

I thought that I needed to add an event to the SightGlassData class that was fired when a property was changed (and then the user control would subscribe to this), but apparently this kind of events is only for run-time use.

**Question:**
How can I ensure that the setter of the `main` property gets called and not only the setter in the `sub` property in the class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're doing something like this:

```
SightGlass.Property = value;
```

This operation doesn't involve the setter. You're `get`ing the `SightGlassData` value, and `set`ting one of its properties. If you want to execute the setter of the `SightGlass` property, you could do for example:

```
SightGlass = new SightGlassData();
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to set the property from the properties window in Visual Studio at design-time...